# In app billing buying products without consuming

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

In my application, i want user to buy some kind of currency, lets say it gold, and spend while using the application. The thing is that, currency isnt fit the Managed Product logic google provides me. Because i want it to be consumed only when a specific action happens and i want my user can buy as much as he wants without consuming.

I know that i can consume the gold immediately after purchase, and write it in a file. But i believe there can be some security problems with this approach.

I made some research on the internet but i couldnt find a solution. I wonder if there is a way to do it without using another server to handle this bussiness. Am i missing something? Is it possible google can store the count of bought objects and reduce them when consumed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Google provides functionality of storing count of purchased objects for you.

In your case, I will go for "consume immediately after purchase".

For security, one suggestion is to save important information on your server.
See [best practices for security and design](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_best_practices.html) for more details.